# Any one-time message sms authentication services?

Tags: web-development

I remember a while back when I used imdb or google apps, I had to enter my phone number and subsequently was texted a short ~5 character code to enter in their online form.  The value I entered in that field was authenticated against the code they texted me.

I wanted to implement that same technology in a web app I'm making.

Are there any one-time message sms authentication services out there?

Answer (score 3):

SMS confirmation is one form of *two-factor authentication*. Here are two providers who offer such a service:

- [DuoSecurity](http://www.duosecurity.com/)
- [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/solutions/two-factor-authentication) (setup guide [here](http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/two-factor-authentication))

You could also consider a two-factor authentication service that doesn't rely on SMS, but instead depends on something else the user has in their possession, like a hardware token or an iPhone/Android device with a special authenticator app installed. DuoSecurity offer this service, as do [Wikid](http://www.wikidsystems.com/) and [Google Authenticator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087005/google-authenticator-available-as-a-public-service).